# Randomize order of displaying nodes?

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to randomize (shuffle) order of displaying nodes in XSLT?
Using `xls:apply-template`, `xls:for-each`, `xls:call-template` etc.

Any trick around?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [random() function in EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/random/) that could be useful